# Converting data frame into sparse matrix triple its size

Tags: r, sparse-matrix

```
library(Matrix)
a<-data.frame(1:1000)
object.size(a)
  4672 bytes

b<-as.matrix(a)
object.size(b)
  4464 bytes

d<-as(b,'dgCMatrix')
object.size(d)
  13520 bytes

e<-Matrix(b, sparse = TRUE)
object.size(e)
 13520 bytes
```

Can anyone tell me why the size of my data frame increases when I converted it into a sparse matrix?

Is sparse matrix conversion become useless when there are no or less zeros in our data frame ? I want a matrix to enter into xgboost.

Can you tell me any other memory saving tricks as sparse matrix conversion seems to be failed in this case ?  please guide

Comment: As far as I know, `sparse matrix` saves memory only when it is sparse? You matrix is obviously a dense matrix, how would you expect it to save memory for you?

Comment: @Psidom is absolutely right; and if you are looking for ways to compress a dense matrix: such methods exist for many cases, but this is a complex topic. Their applicability depends on the context, i.e., on the use of the data in the matrix. A popular example is the compression of image files.

Answer (score 2):

Sparse matrices are - by definition - matrices in which most of the entries are zero. In the case of large and sparse matrices, the computational resources in terms of calculation time and memory requirements can be significantly reduced by representing the data in a compressed scheme.

A commonly used and relatively simple sparse matrix compression scheme consists in representing the matrix as three vectors:

- One vector contains the values of all non-zero entries in the matrix.
- Two further vectors contain the row and column index, respectively, thereby defining the position in the matrix of the non-zero values listed in the first vector.

By using such compression schemes, the storage of numerous zeros can be avoided. Moreover, with these representations it is possible to skip several several useless numerical operations such as time-consuming multiplications with zero. Therefore sparse matrix compression schemes are very powerful *if the matrix is sufficiently large and sparse*.

However, applying a sparse matrix compression method to a dense matrix makes no sense. The reason is that the first vector then has essentially the size of the original matrix. In addition, there are then two integer vectors of the same size. This is consistent with your observation that the total size approximately triples.